# android - issue with finding end of listview in large screens

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a large amount of data and i want to load all of them to a listview so i use below code to find if user scroll to end of the listview and after that i load more data to listview (for example i add another 10 rows to listview) , and at the beginning my listview has 10 row

```
warningListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView lw, final int firstVisibleItem,
                 final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) 
        {   
            final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
               if(lastItem == totalItemCount) 
               {
                  if(preLast!=lastItem)
                  {
                    preLast = lastItem;
                    Utility.parseBadhesabJason(result, getActivity());
                  }
               }
        }
    });
```

my problem with large screens , because in large screens 10 rows fit in screen and there is no scrollbar ! so there is no scrolling ! so there is no loading more data in listview !
have can i handle this ?!

Comment: Utility.parseBadhesabJason(result, getActivity()); what can this line do ??

Comment: this function add another 10 row to listview

Comment: function missing in code

Answer (score 0):

```
loadData(); // load data and populate listview 

/**After loading data check the following condition:**/

int currentPosition = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();

if(currentPosition == list.size()){
    loadMoreData();
}
```